# How to toggle a Formcontrol as disabled or enabled on different button clicks in React/JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, state, prop

I'm new to ReactJS, so I apologize in advance if the questions a bit fragmented.

Basically, I am working on creating a page of a website where someone can change their username and password. I want to implement this in a bootstrap Form where one form control has username, a second has password, etc. One button (edit) will make the FormControl text fields editable (enabled) and the other (save) will make the text fields disabled.

Here's where I run into a problem. From what I've learned of react so far, this involves changing the state. However, the way the prop disabled works, is it isn't "disabled=true" or "disabled=false", it's simply "disabled". Therefore, I can't make it "disabled={this.state.x}" or anything along those lines. Here's the relevant line of code...

```
< FormControl controlId="testControl" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
```

Basically, on a button click (edit) I would like to make this disabled, but I'm unsure of how to do that, when any mention of disabled will result in the FormControl being disabled, regardless of it being set equal to true or false.

Thanks! And please let me know if I can provide more information - as I said, I'm very new to ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to trigger a state change on edit event handler so that react knows to re render the form(which react does intelligently).

Without any state change you will have to manipulate the DOM and achieve whatever you want